# Why does it take more time for data.table::fread to read a file when filename is specified differently?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm reading a file into R using fread using below methods:

```
fread("file:///C:/Users/Desktop/ads.csv")  
fread("C:/Users/Desktop/ads.csv")       # Just omitted "file:///"
```

I've observed the runtime to be very different:

```
microbenchmark(  
fread("file:///C:/Users/Desktop/ads.csv"),  
fread("C:/Users/Desktop/ads.csv")
)

Unit: microseconds
                          expr               min        lq      mean     median       uq       max    neval cld
fread("file:///C:/Users/Desktop/ads.csv") 5755.975 6027.4735 6696.7807 6235.3365 6506.652 41257.476   100   b  
fread("C:/Users/Desktop/ads.csv")          525.492  584.0215  673.7166  647.4745  727.703  1476.191   100   a
```

Why does the run-time vary so much? There isn't noticeable difference between 2 variants when I was using read.csv() though

Comment: I'm wondering how that scales up on a real data set. Measuring stuff in microseconds is usually pointless.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm running a benchmark atm with a dataset with 16,592,802 rows.

Comment: @DavidArenburg https://gist.github.com/JarkoDubbeldam/78fdd854fbb0cdb8b7e1893dc70da4ea With a larger file of 683MB, the difference is around one second (5% difference)

Comment: See the new vignette for advice on proper benchmarking of `data.table`, whose internal optimizations make using something like `microbenchmark` inherently fraught due to, e.g., cacheing

Comment: @MichaelChirico yep, I noticed that caching was messing with the results here. First run takes 3 times longer than the subsequent ones.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Update:

The following has been added to `?fread`:

> When `input` begins with http://, https://, ftp://, ftps://, or file://, `fread` detects this and *downloads* the target to a temporary file (at `tempfile()`) before proceeding to read the file as usual. Secure URLS (ftps:// and https://) are downloaded with `curl::curl_download`; ftp:// and http:// paths are downloaded with `download.file` and `method` set to `getOption("download.file.method")`, defaulting to `"auto"`; and file:// is downloaded with `download.file` with `method="internal"`. NB: this implies that for file://, even files found on the current machine will be "downloaded" (i.e., hard-copied) to a temporary file. See `?download.file` for more details.

---

From the [source of `fread`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/fread.R#L56-L60):

```
if (str6 == "ftp://" || str7 == "http://" || str7 == "file://") {
  method = if (str7 == "file://") "auto"
           else getOption("download.file.method", default = "auto")
  download.file(input, tmpFile, method = method, mode = "wb", quiet = !showProgress)
}
```

That is, your file is being "downloaded" to a temporary file, which should consist of deep-copying the contents of the file to a temporary location. `file://` is not really intended for use on *local* files, but on files in a network that need to be downloaded locally before being read (IIUC; FWIW, this is what `fread`'s testing regime uses to imitate file download while testing on CRAN, where external file download is impossible).

I also notice that your timings are on the order of *microseconds*, which could explain the discrepancy vs. `read.csv`. Imagine `read.csv` takes 1 second to read the file, while `fread` takes .01 seconds; file copying takes `.05` seconds. Then in both cases `read.csv` will look about the same (1 vs 1.05 seconds), while `fread` looks substantially slower for the `file://` case (.01 vs. .06 seconds).

Comment: Actually, those numbers are a strong indicator that caching is going on: The first benchmark reads the file (caching it), stores a copy (possibly with write behind), and then reads the copy (from cache); the second benchmark just reads the file from cache. The difference is the disk access (order of 5 milliseconds) in the latency path of the first benchmark.

Comment: @cmaster oh, that reminds me, this is a good opportunity to highlight the hot-off-the-presses vignette on microbenchmarking `data.table` by Jan Gorecki: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/2684  feedback welcome, it's still in beta!

Comment: @MichaelChirico: By any chance do you have any reference about that `file:///` prefix? I've always wondered what its point is, and why some R functions can handle it while some other can't. (see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1820) for some examples)